# MySQL where-in subquery only returning one row

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-in

I have two tables Courses & Students

Say, Students has fields: `id`, `first_name`
with data

```
id : first_name

1 : Andrew
2 : Brian
3 : Charles
4 : David
5 : Eric
6 : Fred
7 : George
```

Say, Courses has two fields: id & students

With data:

id . . . . .  . . . 1 . . . . . . 2

students . . . 1,2,5. . . .3,4,6,7

Say I want to find the names of students in course 1

`SELECT students FROM courses c WHERE c.id = 1;`

yields 1,2,5  as expected

Also

`SELECT @students := students FROM courses c WHERE c.id =1;`

yields 1,2,5 as expected

And

`SELECT s.first_name FROM students s WHERE s.id IN (1,2,5);`

yields Andrew, Brian Eric as expected

`SET @students := students FROM courses c WHERE c.id =1;`
SELECT @students;`

yields 1, 2, 5

I would expect

`SET @students := students FROM courses c WHERE c.id =1;`
`SELECT s.first_name FROM students s WHERE s.id IN (@students);`

to yield  Andrew, Brian Eric

but it only returns the first name: Andrew

I'm fully aware that I could/should have a separate course_student look-up table but I'm keen to understand why I'm not getting the result I'm expecting

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in how you're using @students; it's defaulting to string* when used in the 'IN' clause.

So your query actually looks like:

```
SELECT s.first_name FROM students s WHERE s.id IN ("1, 2, 5");
```

Unfortunately, this ends up as:

```
SELECT s.first_name FROM students s WHERE s.id IN (1);
```

Either:

```
SELECT s.first_name 
FROM students s 
WHERE s.id IN (
               SELECT students FROM courses c WHERE c.id =1
               )
```

(A classic correlated subquery)

Or:

```
SELECT s.first_name FROM students s WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id`, @students)
```

Or, **more** preferably, use an INNER JOIN as @JohnTotetWoo describes.

*It appears to be defaulting to a string then the resultant cast to int strips off every number after the first comma. However, it could also be just a quirk of the IN clause that ignores everything else in the variable after the first number.

Comment: It works!! SELECT @students := students FROM courses c WHERE c.id =1; SELECT s.first_name FROM students s WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id`, @students) \nThank you for you answers.I thought it must have been a Type problem, I had tried to Cast students as Char, but that didn't seem to work

Comment: I'm now successfully using.....SELECT s.first_name FROM students s WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id`, (SELECT students FROM courses c WHERE c.id =1))

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both tables: `Students` and `Course`, preferablly by using `INNER JOIN`

Try this:

```
SELECT  b.First_name
FROM    Courses a 
            INNER JOIN Students b
                on a.studentID = b.ID
WHERE   a.ID = 1
```

it should return

```
First_Name
==============
Andrew
Brian
Eric
```

Comment: Sadly only gets the first name